# How to display the animation views on the top of buttons like UIAlertView

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I displayed 20 buttons on the view(almost the view is covered with bottons images), now I want to display information using animations on the top of all these buttons like UIAlertView.

Now I am displaying the alert view but instead of that I need to display the animated view on the top of all the buttons.

How can I achieve it, is there any idea to display the information on the top of all the buttons using view animations.

Please help me,
thank you, Madan Mohan.

Comment: Do you mean: tap a button, animate making visible a view that covers this button, or some other sequence?

Comment: @ Mike:Yes, Exactly.....:) The second view should come into front and make animation with displaying appropriate message....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Madan for this you will need two views. If you observe behavior of `UIAlertView` then you will find that when alert view is shown we can not interact with any other item on the view. So one view will serve the purpose for alertview and other will block interaction with `UI`.

You can do this as follows:

Have two views on your `self.view`. One view will hold all the elements that are currently on the self.view and other will have `alertview`. so hierarchy goes like this

```
self.view
   |------------View1
   |               |-----it will have all buttons and other ui that were earlier on self.view
   |
   |-------------View2
                   |------it will have a uiview which you will make,look like alertview.

initially view1 will be at front and view2 will be added at back.
```

Now how to piece all this together.

**When user will tap** on any button the you will need to **bring backview to front** inside `[UIView beginanimation]` and  other animation code and commite it.

and **when user is done** with this view you will **send it to back.**

Also, to make **transparent** look as we have when `alertview` is shown, set View2's `backgroundColor` **black** and `alpha` property 0.3 (or as you wish).

Thanks,

Comment: Can you explain with a piece of code... So that it would be more appreciable, please